# What is needed for a recommendation engine based on word/text input

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine

I'm new to the Machine-Learning (AI) technology. I'm developing a messenger app for Android/IOs where I would like to recommend the users based on the texts/word/conversation a product from a relative small product portfolio.

Example 1:

In case the user of the messenger writes a sentence including the words "vine", "dinner", "date" the AI should recommend a bottle of vine to the user.

Example 2:

In case the user of the app writes that he has drunk a good coffee this morning, the AI should recommend a mug to the user.

Example 3:

In case the user writes something about a cute boy she met last day, the AI should recommend a "teddy bear" to the user.

I'm a Software Developer since almost 20 year with experience in the development of C/C++/Java based application (Android and IOs apps) as well as some experience in Google Cloud Platform. The ML/AI technology is completely new to me. Okay, I know the basics (input data is needed to train the ML/AI system etc.), but I wonder If there is already a framework which could help me to develop such a system which solves the above described uses-case.

I would appreciate it, if you could give me some hints where and how to start.

Thank you and regards

Comment: Where is your ML software running (on mobile or a server in the cloud)?

Comment: @John Hanley It depends on the complexity of the ML system to be used for the described application. I suppose the easiest and more perfomant solution would be to run the ML in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to implement such an application, in case you want to do it in Google Cloud you will need some understanding of Tensorflow.

First of all, I recommend to you to do the [Machine Learning Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/), for a good introduction to Machine Learning and to start to familiarize yourself with TensorFlow. Afterwards I recommend to take a look into [Tensorflow tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) which will give you a more practical introduction to Tensorflow, and include various examples on building/training/testing models.

Once you are famirialized with Tensorflow, you can jump into learning how to run jobs in the Machine Learning engine, you can start by [following the quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction). The documentation includes [detailed guides](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/how-tos) on how to use the ml-engine, plus [multiple samples and tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/tutorials).

Since I believe that your application would fall into the Recommender System type, [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-overview) you can see an example model, in Google Cloud ML Engine, on how to recommend items to users based on his previous searches. In your case, you would have to build a model in order to recommend items to users based on his previous words in the sentence.

The second option, in case you don't want to go through the hassle of building a new model from scratch, would be to use the [Google Cloud Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/), which you can understand as pre-trained models using Google (incredibly big) data. In your case, I believe that the [Content Classifying API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/classifying-text) would help you achieve what your application intends to do, however, the outputs (which you can [see here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/categories)) are limited to what the model was trained to do, and might not be specific enough for your application, however it is an easy solution and you can still profit of this API in order to extract labels/information and send it as input to another model.

I hope that these links provide you with some foundations on what is possible to do with Tensorflow in the ML Engine, and are useful to you.